# startActivity does not launch a new Activity of other app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two android apps(i.e. BIApp and EApp) and I am trying to open EApp from BIApp.
EApp has two activity one is MainActivity and another is LandingPageActivity.

When I try to launch MainActivity using `startActivity(intent)` it works fine but if I try to launch LandingPageActivity. `startActivity(intent)` does nothing.

if EApp is open in background then `startActivity(intent)` works for LandingPageActivity too.

Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.pkg.eapp", "com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to start LandingPageActivity.
What should I do ?

Comment: Share manifest of EApp

Comment: yes @ZygoteInit I saw your answer and added comment too.

Comment: @Karsan: have you tried it ?

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pkg.eapp", "com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and add

```
android:exported="true"
```

and in the `intent-filter` add

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

to the declaration of `LandingPageActivity` in the manifest.

Comment: Nice use of `ComponentName`

Comment: yes @ZygoteInit I saw your answer. But eapp is developed by other team so I request them to change manifest as suggested by you. once they reply I will try this and let you know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is working for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pkg.eapp", "com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [***how to allow Other Apps to Start Your Activity***](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

---

You only need to add `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` category to your Activity onto manifest. Like below

```
<activity android:name="com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.pkg.eapp.action.OPEN_LANDING_PAGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and call it as

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.pkg.eapp.action.OPEN_LANDING_PAGE");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.pkg.eapp", "com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity"));
// Or intent.setPackage("com.pkg.eapp");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but may be LandindPageActivity is not accessible by other apps. In your EApp manifest, do you have an intent filter like this for the LandingPageActivity ?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is not always required

Comment: if LandindPageActivity is not accessible by other app then it should not get open when app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent LaunchIntent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.pkg.eapp.LandingPageActivity");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Hope this might help you.